# Write ArrayBuffer to file in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, arraybuffer

I am using Microsoft Cognitive Service Speech SDK for Nodejs to convert text to speech.

The SDK is giving me the resulting audio as ArrayBuffer.

[image]

How do I write this ArrayBuffer to an mp3 file or upload it to S3?

Comment: What are the missing parts of your solution?  What part of this is giving you trouble? 
 Keep in mind that asking for a recommendation for an mp3 library could be considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: I am not asking for an mp3 library recommendation. I want to know how do I go from audio data which is in ArrayBuffer to a file.

Comment: Did you try the most basic approach?  `fs.writeFileSync('output.raw', Buffer.from(privAudioData))`

Comment: that's what I was looking for. thanks!